# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument, when reading files by line using Python

Tags: python, file, io

I'm trying to get rid of some error lines in a very large file (200GB on Windows), the code is basically as follows

```
with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as fi:
    with open(outputfile, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fo:
        while True:
            try:
                line = next(fi)
                fo.write(line)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                line = next(fi)
                continue
```

However I got this `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument` from the `line = next(fi)` line inside the try block after having processed about 30GB data. What is the possible reason for this? how could I handle it?

Also I noticed weird memory allocation behavior around this point, it first blows up to full memory size then went down to its original level, I don't know if this is relevant or just coincidence though.

The full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/concat_split_files.py", line 23, in <module>
    line = next(fi)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

---

**EDIT** Here's the exact code, the main difference is that since I have already successfully checked part of the file, I skipped the first few lines (30GB).

```
filename = r"data.tsv"
outputfile2 = r"p2.tsv"
line_no = 306878

with open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as fi:
    for _ in range(line_no):
        try:
            next(fi)
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            line = next(fi)
            print(line)
            continue

    with open(outputfile2, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fo2:
        while True:
            try:
                line = next(fi)
                fo2.write(line)
            except UnicodeDecodeError:
                line = next(fi)
                print(line)
                continue
            except StopIteration:
                break
```

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question..

Comment: @KlausD. Sure it's just simply two lines like `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument from line line = next(fi)`, I'll paste the full stacktrace after reproducing it. :)

Comment: *the code is basically as follows* Please post your **exact** code.  If you're having "weird memory allocatoin behavior" when the process fails, the exact code will be necessary so others can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle added thanks!

Comment: What if you use `line = fi.readline()` or directly iterate using `for line in fi:`?

Comment: @7t7Studios I tried, it's the same error :/

Answer (score 1):

It turned out the file was incomplete. So I guess at some point the actual data ends without a line break, then the program just kept reading the file until the memory blew up and threw this error.